# How to serialize a big dict to a disk file, such that small modifications don't require a full rewrite, but only a few bytes?

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary, serialization, diff

Let's work with a big dictionary (110 MB) and save it to disk:

```
import pickle, os
d = {i: os.urandom(100) for i in range(1_000_000)}  
with open('mydict', 'wb') as f:  
    pickle.dump(d, f)           # 110 MB file
```

Now let's do small modifications (only 2 key/values changed among 1 million):

```
d[17] = "hello"  # addition
del d[1234]      # deletion
with open('mydict', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(d, f)           # we're rewriting 110 MB to disk again! unefficient!
```

**How to avoid to rewrite the whole dict?**

Which serialization techniques to use that such small modifications on `d` only requires a few bytes to write on disk?

Of course, a database (e.g. Sqlite) could be a solution, but I wanted to see first if there are even easier techniques.

Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
before_modification_state = d.getstate()
d[17] = "hello"  # addition
del d[1234]      # deletion
diff = d.getdiff(from=before_modification_state)   # only a few bytes

patch('mydict', diff)   # this only writes a few bytes to the disk file "mydict"

# or

with open('mydict', 'r+') as f:  # read-write
    for pos, newbytes in diff:
        f.seek(pos)         # move to position pos
        f.write(newbytes)   # write the new bytes
# with this solution d.getdiff() would return something like 
# [[6576, b"fsq678"], [16537, b"!/=13IH"]]
# i.e. position to seek in file, and new bytes to write
```

Or is there another data structure more adapted for this?

---

Edit: As suggested in a comment, I tried with `shelve`:

```
import shelve
d = shelve.open("dict2")
for i in range(1_000_000):
    d[str(i)] = os.urandom(100)
```

but this takes 300 seconds and 514 MB! (and with `writeback=True` it's the same).

As a comparison, with the first code above (modified to have `str(i)` instead of `i` as keys to have a fair comparison - [shelve doesn't support integer keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734821/why-does-pythons-shelve-require-that-all-keys-be-strings)), it takes 4 seconds and 120 MB only.

So it seems `shelve` is not well adapted here.

Also, `shelve` is basically just [`dbm`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html) with `pickle` for the the dict values. So it's worth looking at `dbm` directly. Unfortunately on Windows, only [`dbm.dumb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html#module-dbm.dumb) is available, and it's a bit weak: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/dbm/dumb.py#L11, *"Currently, space once occupied by deleted or expanded items is never reused"*.

Comment: Binary formats are usually quite complex, so they're not easy to "patch" in-place. In most cases, implementing such functionality would be more trouble than it's worth. If you're just trying to reduce the amount of disk writes, you could calculate a dictionary of the differences and write that to the disk as a separate file?

Comment: It seems that you need a [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shelve.html), see also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114616/remove-or-edit-entry-saved-with-python-pickle) (and answer).

Comment: @Basj Updated the comment :)

Comment: @DaniMesejo would you have a sample code of my example from the question, showing that with shelves, only a few bytes are written during the second serialization?

Comment: @Basj I can point you to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661085/shelve-writes-blank-lists-dictionarys) it clearly states that shelve only write changes. I cannot think of an example of how to prove it.

Comment: @DaniMesejo see my edit, with `shelve` it takes 300 seconds and 514 MB instead of 4 seconds and 120 MB with `pickle`. Or maybe is there a way to improve my addition of entries with this loop (see the last code snippet of my question)?

Comment: You could append new entries to the end of a YAML file, if your dict was at the end.  Not sure that YAML is very quick to load in Python however.

Comment: @DaniMesejo In fact `shelve` is basically just [`dbm`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html) with `pickle` for the the dict values. See my last question edit at the end.

Comment: @Basj so shelve is out of the question?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a very fast write, you could just append it to a YAML file, at the end, using regular text mode.  Last key value "wins".

So your write speed is basically as per appending one line each time.  Read speed would be slow because of YAML, but you could always read/write in YAML mode to strip out duplicate data.

Note:  YAML, not JSON, because JSON requires ending the file with a '}`or`]`, which complicates things.

#### test.py

```
from yaml import safe_load as yload, safe_dump as ydump
import sys
from pathlib import Path

pa_yaml = Path(__file__).with_suffix(".yaml")
value = sys.argv[1]

if pa_yaml.exists():
    existed = True
    with pa_yaml.open("a") as fo:
        fo.write(f"value: {value}\n")
else:
    existed = False
    data = dict(dummy="dummy", value=value)
    print("seeding test.yaml with {data=}")
    with pa_yaml.open("w") as fo:
        fo.write(ydump(data))

print(f"\n{pa_yaml} contents after write:\n{pa_yaml.read_text()}")
with pa_yaml.open() as fi:
    data = yload(fi)
    print(f"after write {data=}")
```

#### output:

```
(venv38) me@test_206_yaml$ python test.py value1
seeding test.yaml with {data=}

test.yaml contents after write:
dummy: dummy
value: value1

after write data={'dummy': 'dummy', 'value': 'value1'}
(venv38) me@test_206_yaml$ python test.py value2

test.yaml contents after write:
dummy: dummy
value: value1
value: value2

after write data={'dummy': 'dummy', 'value': 'value2'}
(venv38) me@test_206_yaml$ python test.py value3

test.yaml contents after write:
dummy: dummy
value: value1
value: value2
value: value3

after write data={'dummy': 'dummy', 'value': 'value3'}
```

integer keys worked fine.  I tested by adding `{4:4}` to the seed value.

Comment: Thanks for this nice solution! I finally used a few days ago something quite similar with the same philosophy *"you could just append it to a YAML file, at the end, using regular text mode. Last key value "wins"."* It works well indeed!